# How to get formatted date using moment.js and convert it into timestamp using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datetime, timestamp, momentjs

I have an application where I need to show the date in UI like `DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss` and again this date to timestamp.

What I have tried:

```
$scope.dateForUI = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Here I am getting the expected result. But I need timestamp of $scope.dateForUI as well. So I have tried

```
$scope.dateInTimestamp = moment().unix($scope.get_date_line);
```

But the console output shows the `1970` date in `$scope.dateInTimestamp`

My question is how I format my current date and assign it to a variable and again how to get the timestamp for this particular time.

Another thing is it possible to store the time of any timezone in to my `$scope.dateForUI` variable using moment.js? I need to show the IST time in every browser location.

Very new to moment.js, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.dateInTimeStamp = moment().unix();
```

Comment: this returns 1486049689

Comment: Full timestamp will be returned using `moment().valueOf()`

Comment: I have formatted the object like $scope.dateForUI = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"); Mozzila has issue with this.

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer in other word be more descriptive, code only answer doesn't tend to help much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to get values in fixed timezone. For example:

```
moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata")
```

Use [`moment.unix(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) to get moment object from *seconds since the Unix Epoch*

Moreover you can use [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) to get milliseconds since the Unix Epoch from moment object and [`.unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) to get seconds.

Here a snippet to show how moment-timezone works and how you can use `unix()`:

```js
// basic angular mock
var $scope = {};
// Current time in India (moment object)
var momNow = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata");
// Current time in India formatted (string)
$scope.dateForUI = momNow.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
// Current time in India as seconds from 1970 (number)
$scope.dateInTimestamp = momNow.unix();

console.log($scope.dateForUI);
console.log($scope.dateInTimestamp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is Number here?

Comment: `Number` is _seconds since the Unix Epoch_ see linked example in the docs. If I understand well `$scope.get_date_line` is the number in your code.

Comment: What is the issue with Firefox? Anyway I've edited my answer including a live snippet trying to show clearer how moment an moment-timezone work.